# How to disable past dates in Bootstrap datetimepicker after set check in date

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I know how to disable past days from current date.
its working with [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/65vaoqkw/7/)

but my problem is how can I disable previous dates after select `check in` date.

**my jquery**

```
$(function () {

        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });
        $('#from_date').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });
        $('#to_date').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });
    });
```

**my view**

```
<div class='col-md-offset-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' name="from_date" id="from_date" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='col-sm-3 col-xs-6'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
            <input type='text' name="to_date" id="to_date" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='col-sm-1 col-xs-12'>
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="search">SEARCH</button>
</div>
```

[image]
any help please.

Comment: What do you mean by `check in` date?

Comment: You mean, you want to disable previous dates after user selects a date and from that selected date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried like this

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({  minDate:new Date('2016-10-25')}); //set check in date here
```

**EDIT**

For Format date

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({  
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    minDate:new Date('2016-10-25')
});
```

**EDIT**

Set From and To Dynamically

Please see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sojitrar88/xgtrpdsp/5/)

Comment: yes I tried it but if I set `minDate:new Date('2016-10-25')` calendar not showing.

Comment: please give jsfiddle link

Comment: thanks,but if I set it how can I add `format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'` this date format important to my work.

Comment: thank you,How can I change `2016-10-25` to `selected check in date` in check out calender.

Comment: Please see My updated answer and see fiddle link added last in my answer

Answer (score 1):

In case of  https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Options/

you can try set the range of allowed dates like

**JS**

```
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);

var yesterday = new Date();
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);

$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    minDate: yesterday,
    maxDate: tomorrow,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just override the minDate property in your datetimepicker

```
var checkin = '2016-10-24';
$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(checkin);
```

Comment: I tried this but its not working. calendar not showing after set this jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to control the end date to be greater than start date, if this is the case below code might help you, it's checking if the start date is less than or equal end date, and if end date is greater than or equal start date, then it sets the minimum time period for bookings, you can set it as you would like, or just set the **.minDate('#start').val()** to the end date, console log sections are commented out as they are only for debugging purposes:

```
$('#Start').on("dp.change",
                  function(e)
                  {
                        if (dateSorter($('#End').val(), $(this).val()) === -1 || dateSorter($('#End').val(), $(this).val()) === 0)
                            // if ($('#End').val() < $(this).val())
                        {
                         //   console.log("End date "+$('#End').val()+ " is beofre start date: "+ $(this).val()+" Setting minimum booking period");
                            $('#End').data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date.add(30, 'minutes'));
                        }

                    });
$('#End').on("dp.change",
                 function(e)
                  {
                     if (dateSorter($('#Start').val(), $(this).val()) === 1 || dateSorter($('#Start').val(), $(this).val()) === 0)
                     // if ($('#Start').val() >= $(this).val())
                     {
                        //   console.log("Start date " + $('#Start').val() + " is after end date: " + $(this).val()+" Setting minimum booking period");
                        $(this).data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date.add(30, 'minutes'));
                     }                       
               });
```

If you want to add formatting (this is a date time picker), you can use this script:

```
 $(".datePickerTime").datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: false,
        useCurrent: false,
        showClear: true,
        showClose: true,
        locale: "en-au",
        format: "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A",
        sideBySide: true,
        toolbarPlacement: "bottom"

    });
```

For only a date picker use as:

```
 $(".datePicker").datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: false,
        useCurrent: false,
        showClear: true,
        showClose: true,

    locale: 'en-au',
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});
```